# Database design - table relationship question

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I am designing schema for a simple quiz application. It has 2 tables - "Question" and "Answer Choices". Question table has 'question ID', 'question text' and 'answer id' columns. "Answer Choices" table has 'question ID', 'answer ID' and 'answer text' columns. With this simple schema it is obvious that a question can have multiple answer choices & hence the need for the answer choices table. However, a question can have only one correct answer and hence the need for the 'answer ID' in the question table. However, this 'answer ID' column in the question table provides a illusion as though there can be multiple questions for a single answer which is not correct. The other alternative to eliminate this illusion is to have another table just for correct answer that will have just 2 columns namely the question ID and the answer ID with a 1-1 relationship between the two tables. However, I think this is redundant. Any recommendation on how best to design this thereby enforcing the rules that a question can have multiple answer choices but only one correct answer? Many Thanks.

Comment: Whatever you do, no matter which one you choose, please, for the love of god, do not call the PK of every table ID.

Comment: @Stephanie Page: Please, for the love of God, reason why do you say so?

Comment: Not enough room in a comment for a full dissertation but... say you have a multiple table query (say 5). You have five columns all named exactly the same, all meaning completely different things. Would you accept that for any other column? Would you allow the column "COST" to mean 5 different things in five different tables? Would you want to call them, "TOTAL_COST", "DIRECT_COST", "AVERAGE_COST", etc? SO why would you do that with ID? That's just one in a list of reasons not to. And the people on the other side have only one argument, keystrokes. In this day, that's a poor excuse.

Comment: @Stephanie Page: Still does not make any sense for my case. In my schema as explained above, I have named them as 'question ID' and 'answer id' and not as 'ID' as you claim & commented further.

Comment: @Steph - i tend to agree.. the ID columns will be prefixed by a table name or alias anyway - so not confusing.

Comment: @iama, I think you're a little over sensitive. Where did I CLAIM anything? I never said YOU have done so, I encouraged you NOT to do it because some answers did. Other ANSWERS provided by OTHER PEOPLE BELOW use that naming. I said no matter which answer you CHOOSE don't also adopt their NAMING. you need a nice girlfriend or some wine to relax.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the `AnswerID` column from the `Question` table. You're creating a (sort-of) circular reference. Instead, have an `IsCorrect` bit (boolean) column in the `Answer` table. This will also afford you flexibility to have multiple correct answers in the future should you need that facility.

Per Matti's point, a trigger on INSERT/UPDATE of an Answer-record will enforce the zero-or-one correct answer per question rule.

Comment: That, however, requires you to create additional rules to enforce that only one answer for each question can be marked as correct.

Comment: @Matti - good point. An INSERT/UPDATE trigger would do the trick.

Comment: the IsCorrect bit field in the choices table is the most flexible approach as you can, if required in the future, have multiple correct answers for a question simply by toggling a field value 0 or 1.

Comment: This was the approach I thought initially but did not want to implement 'coz it will leave too many gaps in the Answer choices table 'coz clearly there can only be one correct answer to any question.

Comment: @iama - could you clarify what you mean by "gaps"? Thanks!

Comment: @Bob - By gaps I mean most of the answer choices will have false or null as the value since there can be only one correct answer.

Comment: @iama - This doesn't quite fit, but "entropy" may be the term we're grasping for. Nothing wrong with an underutilized field, just like student's sex at The Citidel (http://www.citadel.edu/main/) Read more about entropy here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29

Answer (score 2):

How about just naming the column `CorrectAnswerId`? I doubt anybody would mistake that for anything else.

Comment: @Bob +1 for acknowledging this, not common on SO

Comment: I am assuming you are asking me to rename the column name in the question table to "CorrectAnswerID". I can certainly do that but I guess it still does not change the original issue. It will still appear as though answer choices table has 1:N relationship with the question table. This is not a big deal. I just wanted to know if there was any better design given my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Three tables (because you can have many "Yes" "No", why duplicate that, and you can change later a "No" to a "Nop" easily).
the `questions_answers` table would map some answers to some questions. (It's a many to many relationship).

questions:

- id
- description
- correct_answer_id

answers:

- id
- description

questions_answers:

- question_id
- answer_id

Comment: you may also consider another table to identify users and another to identify what answers a given user selected...

Answer (score 0):

**questions**
- id
- question_text

```
1, "left or right?"
```

**answer_choices**
- id
- question_id
- answer_text
- correct

```
1, 1, "left", 1
2, 1, "right", 0
```

**answers**
- id
- question_id
- user_id
- answer_choices_id

```
1, 1, 1234, 2 // wrong!
1, 1, 5678, 1 // yay
```

So, basically you first query the question from the `questions` table, and then query the possible answers from the `answer_choices` table that are linked to the question by `question_id`. When an answer has been given, you take the selected `answer_choices_id` and check it against the `answer_choices` table to see if `correct` is 1 or 0.

Comment: What does the ID on the answers table do?

Comment: Simply a unique identifier for a user's answer. Whether it's useful depends on the use. You can also drop it and use `question_id` combined with `user_id` to identify it.

Comment: Having correct field in the answer choices table leaves too many gaps since there can be only one correct answer to any question. Instead you could have the correct field in the question table or create another table with just the question ID and the correct field. However, my problem is not that. How best can we design these tables so that there is no redundancy or duplicates.